# What is the effective way to have a pivot-table having pandas dataset columns as its rows?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

Let's take as an example the following dataset:

```
    make    address all     3d   our    over    length_total    y
0   0.0     0.64    0.64    0.0  0.32   0.0     278             1
1   0.21    0.28    0.5     0.0  0.14   0.28    1028            1
2   0.06    0.0     0.71    0.0  1.23   0.19    2259            1
3   0.15    0.0     0.46    0.1  0.61   0.0     1257            1
4   0.06    0.12    0.77    0.0  0.19   0.32    749             1
5   0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0  0.0    0.0     21              1
6   0.0     0.0     0.25    0.0  0.38   0.25    184             1
7   0.0     0.69    0.34    0.0  0.34   0.0     261             1
8   0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0  0.9    0.0     25              1
9   0.0     0.0     1.42    0.0  0.71   0.35    205             1
10  0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0  0.0    0.0     23              0
11  0.48    0.0     0.0     0.0  0.48   0.0     37              0
12  0.12    0.0     0.25    0.0  0.0    0.0     491             0
13  0.08    0.08    0.25    0.2  0.0    0.25    807             0
14  0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0  0.0    0.0     38              0
15  0.24    0.0     0.12    0.0  0.0    0.12    227             0   
16  0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0  0.75   0.0     77              0
17  0.1     0.0     0.21    0.0  0.0    0.0     571             0
18  0.51    0.0     0.0     0.0  0.0    0.0     74              0
19  0.3     0.0     0.15    0.0  0.0    0.15    155             0
```

I want to get pivot-table from the previous dataset, in which the columns (make, address    all, 3d, our, over, length_total) will have their mean values processed by the column y. The following table is the expected result:

```
                    y   
                    1   0
make            0.048   0.183
address         0.173   0.008
all             0.509   0.098
3d              0.01    0.02
our             0.482   0.123
over            0.139   0.052
length_total    626.7   250
```

Is it possible to get the desired result through pivot_table method from pandas.data object? If so, how?

Is there a more effective way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some people like using `stack` or `unstack`, but I prefer good ol' [`pd.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) to "flatten" or "unpivot" a frame:

```
>>> df_m = pd.melt(df, id_vars="y")
>>> df_m.pivot_table(index="variable", columns="y")
                value         
y                   0        1
variable                      
3d              0.020    0.010
address         0.008    0.173
all             0.098    0.509
length_total  250.000  626.700
make            0.183    0.048
our             0.123    0.482
over            0.052    0.139
```

(If you want to preserve the original column order as the new row order, you can use `.loc` to index into this, something like `df2.loc[df.columns].dropna()`).

---

Melting does the flattening, and preserves `y` as a column, putting the old column names as a new column called `"variable"` (which can be changed if you like):

```
>>> pd.melt(df, id_vars="y").head()
   y variable  value
0  1     make   0.00
1  1     make   0.21
2  1     make   0.06
3  1     make   0.15
4  1     make   0.06
```

After that we can call `pivot_table` as we would ordinarily.

Comment: Here is a little change to work with Pandas v 0.13.1.
     df_m.pivot_table(rows="variable", cols="y")